# Applications run, don't display

Tags: 14.04, software-center, pidgin

I'm new to Ubuntu and Linux.  The preinstalled programs work fine, but anything that I download from Ubuntu Software Center such as `Pidgin` or `Chromium` or from online runs (I can hear the sounds of Pidgin) but don't display when opened.

When I do an <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>, I can see a thumbnail of the GUI but can't do anything

When I run them from the terminal, I get the following messages:

```
Chromium - ATTENTION: default value of option force_s3tc_enable overridden by environment.
Pidgin - Exiting because another libpurple client is already running.
```

Comment: Try running them from the terminal, do you get any output? If so, please [edit] it into your question. Thanks!

Comment: Added new information.  The programs are definately "running" I just can't seem to reach them if that makes any sense

Comment: Try after `kill -9 -1` this will restart all process you can.

Comment: Tried it.  Doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: I am having a similar problem in chromium http://askubuntu.com/questions/519549/in-chromium-37-0-2062-94-ubuntu-14-04-290621-window-restore-is-delayed

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after upgrading. I went to System Settings\Screen Display and found that the upgrade process had dug up some old dual monitor config from ages ago and enabled a monitor that was no longer connected. Once I disabled that the apps appeared on my actual monitor.